# Python package for option pricing models?

Tags: option-pricing, python

Is there a good python package for various option pricing models, e.g., Heston, SABR, etc? I found that it's even hard to find a good python implementation of Black-Scholes model (i.e., price + IV + all Greeks implemented in a class).

I know there's QuantLib python, but it is implemented in C/C++. Not to mention I have to install C/C++ compiler, it's quite difficult to quickly test/change for new ideas for research purpose.

Comment: I know your question was from a long time ago, but what alternative did you end up chosing?

Comment: @H.L. I ended up creating one myself. The package is called `pyfeng`. See https://pypi.org/project/pyfeng/

Comment: You should look at https://github.com/domokane/FinancePy

Answer (score 4):

If you follow the below instructions, you won't need a C++ compiler. Also, you don't care what language the library is implemented in, all you have to do is call the functions.

> **Installation from PyPI**
>
> If you don't need to modify the wrappers, you might want to try installing a precompiled binary version. The availability of binaries depend on your operating system; to try to install them, run:
>
> > pip install QuantLib-Python
>
> If a binary package is available for your system, it will be installed and you will be able to leave this page and use it right away; if not, you'll have to compile it yourself as described in the next section.
>
> source: https://www.quantlib.org/install/windows-python.shtml

Comment: Thanks. Changing code won't be easy with QunatLib-Python, but it'll be still helpful, e.g., for checking against my implementation.

Comment: @JaehyukChoi what are you actually trying to do? Changing the code of the library defeats the purpose of using a third-party library.

Comment: I want to modify codes for research purposes, e.g. testing new methods, etc. It's always easier to do from existing code than from scratch.